# Correlation in R

Tags: r, correlation

I am trying to produce same graph as in [example](http://rgm2.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/func.php?rd_id=SciViews:correlation) but using different data. Here is my code:

```
library(SciViews)

args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
pdfname <- args[1]
datafile <- args[2]

pdf(pdfname)
eqdata = read.csv(datafile , header = T,sep=",")
(longley.cor <- correlation(eqdata$feqs))
# Synthetic view of the correlation matrix
summary(longley.cor) 
p <- plot(longley.cor)
print(p)
dev.off()
```

and the data

```
ques,feqs
"abc",20
"def",10
"ghi",40
"jkl",10
"mno",20
"pqr",10
```

I use this command

```
Rscript ./rscript/correlation.R "/home/co.pdf" "/home/data_correlation.csv"
```

[image]

**Code output**

[image]

I want to generate like this

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I am not familiar with `SciViews` but still quite sure that computing `correlation` for only one variable of a data frame is not a good idea.

Comment: Many thanks for you suggestion. I want to generate correlation of text... So just considering frequency of each word at the moment. Any idea for text correlation?

Comment: If the variables you want to correlate are the frequencies of `'abc'`, `'def', etc., then you need more than one value for each variable. In your example each variable has only one value, and you cannot calculate the covariance of things that don't actually vary.

Comment: @Marius you are right. I have to format data like this

 
 >"abc","def","ghi","jkl","mno","pqr"
 >10,20,10,12,13,10
 >12,13,13,14,30,10
 >40,12,40,44,12,30
 


and its closer to my requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the `plotcorr` function in the `ellipse` package. The help pages gives among others this example:

[image]

Which seems to be what you are looking for?

## Edit:

You can add text afterwards, the circles are placed on a 1 - number of vars grid. E.g.:

```
data(mtcars)
Corrmat  <- cor(mtcars)
cols <- ifelse(Corrmat>0, rgb(0,0,abs(Corrmat)), rgb(abs(Corrmat),0,0))

library(ellipse)
plotcorr(Corrmat,col=cols)

n <- nrow(Corrmat)
for (i in 1:n)
{
    for (j in 1:n)
    {
        text(j,i,round(Corrmat[n-i+1,j],2),col="white",cex=0.6)     
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks sacha, I need to display correlation on each ellipse. I could generate above graph but having problem with labels... in label instead of space its replaced with dot(.) do you have any idea,how to fix it?

Comment: I am still using SciViews package.